# Is it possible to change the resource type in CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I would like to separate out my template into nested stacks.

So I would need to change my resource from:

```
  CDN:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
```

To:

```
  CDN:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
```

But I'm not allowed to deploy because I can't change the type of the resource.

```
Update of resource type is not permitted. The new template modifies resource type of the following resources: [CDN]
```

I need to delete the resource, then redeploy it as the nested stack.

Is there a way to not delete and recreate the resource, but rather "transfer" the resource to the nested stack? I would like to not delete the CloudFront distribution to avoid downtime.

Comment: No. There is no such way.

Answer (score 0):

You can move a resource from one stack to another by using the [`DeletionPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) attribute, along with the [CloudFormation import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) mechanism.

The procedure would look something like this:

1. Modify the template for your existing stack to add the property `DeletionPolicy: Retain` to your `CDN` resource, then perform a stack update.  This should not incur any downtime.
2. Remove the resource from the template completely, and then update the stack again.  This step is slightly scary, but because you had marked the resource as `Retain` in the previous step, it should not actually delete the resource, it will just delete it from the *stack*.  At this point, the distribution is still up and running, but it is "orphaned" from any CloudFormation stack.
3. Create a new template representing your nested stack.  This template should have the `CDN` resource, just as it existed in your previous stack (though it doesn't need to have the same logical resource ID).
4. Create a change set for the new nested stack, specifying an IMPORT operation with the identifier of the existing CloudFormation distribution.  If there are other new resources in your nested stack, you might need to create those first, without the `CDN` resource in your template, then do the import operation as a separate change set.  I seem to remember you can't create new resources and import existing resources in the same change set, but I could be wrong about that.  In either case, once you are done you will have a regular old nested CloudFormation stack containing your original distribution which can be updated normally from that point forward.

This does not necessarily require you to change the resource in the previous stack to `AWS:Serverless::Application` ... however, you are now at liberty to do that, since the resource has effectively been deleted from that stack.  If you recreated the `CDN` resource in the previous stack, CloudFormation would treat it as if you are creating a brand new resource as opposed to changing the type of an existing resource.